# What sets the maximum position value when getView is called? (Shrinking a ListView)

Tags: android

I'm displaying a ListView and at first it works just fine - everything displays and scrolls OK.   There are 12 items in the ListView.      Then I try to reduce the number of items in the ListView, so I reduce the size of dataset and it crashes in the adapter's *getView()* because *getView()* is called with a position value too big for the new, smaller list, resulting in an array index out of bounds.

**Source Snippets:**

In *onCreate()* I attach my listview to the XML

```
   setContentView(R.layout.mylist);
   lv = getListView();
```

I create the adapter and bind it . . .

```
mylistadapter = new MyListAdapter(MyListActivity.this);
setListAdapter(mylistadapter);   // bind the adapter
```

...the data source is an ArrayList called listItems. The first time around it has 12 items in it; later I clear it and add in 6 items.

```
public static ArrayList<String>listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
```

After I clear it and add the 6 new items I call *notifyDataSetChanged()*.

In my adapter, which is a BaseAdapter, my override of *getCount()* looks like this. After shrinking listItems to 6 it correctly returns 6.

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
```

To verify *notifyDataSetChanged()* was getting called I wrote an overrride of it to do logging and to prove to myself that it was really getting called.   With or without this override the behavior is the same.

```
// just overriding notifyDataSetChanged() to instrument it
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() 
{
    Log.e ("notifyDataSetChanged()...",   "listItems.size()=" + String.valueOf(listItems.size()) + "  lv.getCount()=" + String.valueOf(lv.getCount()) );   //!! debugging
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The *getView()* looks like this.  It blows up at the BOOM comment because position is 6 and listItems only has 6 items ([0]-[5]

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    boolean select;

        Log.e ("getView() ...  " , "position=" + String.valueOf(position) + 
                   " AdapterCount=" + String.valueOf(getCount()) + "..." );   //!! debugging            
        if (convertView == null) {      
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.mylistitem, null);
            //This is still needed even though we point to an XML description
            convertView.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(
                    ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.cV1.setTag(holder);  //These views need tags for onClick()
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        int lvCount = lv.getCount();  // for debugging
        //Must set this in both cases        
        holder.itemView.setText(listItems.get(position));  //BOOM


        return convertView;

    }  // end getView
```

Since the adapter knows there are only 6 items in its dataset, listItems, it should only call *getView()* with [0]-[5], but in fact it calls it with position values up to [11], which was the maximum value of the old list.  That's why it's crashing.   You can see where I also get the ListView's count, for diagnostics; it's also 6.   So where are the higher position values coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Did you call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after clearing the listview?

```
@Override
public void clear()
{
    listItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Yes, as I said:  quote:  "After I clear it and add the 6 new items I call notifyDataSetChanged(). "